# Is there a way to tell if a transaction provides liquidity?

Tags: transactions

Is there a way to tell if a transaction involves a user providing liquidity? For example, in this transaction I am providing liquidity using Raydium. I am trying to tag other transactions that provide liquidity given a wallet address. Is there a way to do this maybe by analyzing the accounts array or the instructions? Any resources or advice would be greatly appreciated!

example tx: https://solscan.io/tx/5xLFfoL7qyM1thHfbfyT3zu8zeG3CqXfyCwfreFLuud4meZzYZ9haMi5LR3M8mM62GFoBLSoxAnSj8hkgn6BXx5v

Answer (score 1):

Being as the explorer can identify the fourth instruction as "add liquidity", you should be able to scan all transactions for Raydium instructions with the same discriminator (3? probably dig through their code to confirm)